# images not shown in a website in IE

Tags: javascript, html

i have a web site, herer i have implemented a slide show. While browsing it's correct in Mozilla. But in IE it's not working. But the images are already present in the folder. Then why it's not shown in IE?

Does any one know this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a code example or check if you have any errors in IE?

Comment: You need to post some code. In IE press F12 to get up the dev console, and check to see if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: How can we possibly help you without seeing this website of yours ?

Comment: http://www.chemmanurinternational.com/

Comment: If you're talking about the "what's happenning" slideshow, it works in IE7>9. Clear the browser's cache maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [image](http://www.chemmanurinternational.com/admin/product_images/homescreen/homescreen_1327145330.jpg) is a [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) image:

> JPEG, CMYK, U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2

IE doesn't do CMYK. Use Photoshop or some other image editing tool to convert the image to RGB.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's Firebug says:

http://www.chemmanurinternational.com/:1105

```
window.addEvent is not a function
window.addEvent('load', function () {
```

and
http://www.chemmanurinternational.com/:107

```
$("div#mygalone").slideView is not a function
...load", function() { $("div#mygalone").slideView({toolTip: true, ttOpacity: 0.5})...
```

Although the errors it still works. I think if you fix those errors IE will work as well.